# How to get block handle of Interpreted Matlab function from its .m function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an interpreted MATLAB function in my Simulink model. I want to get the block handle or port-handle of this block from user defined `.m` function implemented in it (say it `test.m`).

I tried

```
h = get_param(gcb, 'PortHandles'); % for port handle   
b = gcbh ;                         % for block handle
```

Both gives port handle/block handle for recently clicked block, which I don't want. I want the port handle/Block  handle of the interpreted MATLAB function, which is executing this code via `.m` function (`test.m`). Is there any way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`getSimulinkBlockHandle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/getsimulinkblockhandle.html) maybe?

Comment: It needs block path, which can vary one model to another model.so getSimulinkBlockHandle will not work for me. I mean is there a command where it get's the block path automatically, like gcb do. BTW gcb is not useful for my case As I explained in my question

Comment: To my knowledge that is not possible, but maybe you can describe what you want to achieve. It is probably possible using a [MATLAB S-Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html) instead.