# Get the handle of a block calling an Interpreted Matlab Function

Tags: simulink, handle

I am using Simulink to model a waste recycling plant out of a number of masked blocks that I created, representing sorting steps, buffers etc. Each module (that is, a masked block) has a failure probability, modeled using Discrete Events. If a failure event occurs, a triggered subsystem calls an Interpreted Matlab Function ("outside" of simulink). This function is supposed to set a parameter `status` of the masked block representing the module that failed as well as the upstream modules' `status` to 0 (because obviously, everything upstream has to stop as well or the material will just pile up).

```
`set_param(gcb, 'status', num2str(status));
PortConnectivity = get_param(gcb,'PortConnectivity');
sources = PortConnectivity.SrcBlock;`
```

Basically, this will be looped until I reach a block with no own Source Block. 
This all works quite well, except for one problem: The `gcb` command gives me the block path to the last block I highlighted manually, and not to the block that called the Interpreted Matlab function. Is there any way to get the calling block's handle (which I would use with it's `Parents` parameter to access the Mask's `status`)? (A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425619/how-to-get-block-handle-of-interpreted-matlab-function-from-its-m-function), with no results...)

I hope you get my problem - I'll be happy to elaborate if anything's unclear; I am not claiming to be a Simulink expert, so sorry for maybe using wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for everyone stumbling upon this: 
For the mask that contains the caller of the Matlab Interpreted Function, in the mask editor I define a parameter 'this_block' (turn visibility off), that I initialize in the Initialisation pane using

```
parent = get_param(gcb,'Parent');
set_param(gcb, 'this_block','Parent')
```

Since this masked block (responsible for modelling the failure and its upstream communication) is itself used in another masked block also present in the library (responsible for modeling the module's behaviour), I also had to check "Allow library blocks to modify it's contents" in the mask editor Inititlization pane of the parent's mask. The parameter 'this_block' is then handed over as one of the input arguments of the called function (in my case, status_communication(u, this_block)).